# How to visualize gates of LSTM for time-series data?

Tags: visualization, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I'm currently implementing LSTM to classify 5 types of my time-series data. 
LSTM currently achieves 85% classification accuracy.
I would like to understand how the input gate, output gate and memory cell work before going further. The best way I can think of is to visualize these gates w.r.t my data.

I've searched a lot of work w.r.t LSTM and find a post describing re-implementing the visualization of Microsoft paper [visualization gates](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/issues/1922). However, I don't quite understand it. Can anyone shed light on visualizing these gates? Any information would be appreciated! Thanks!

Besides, as far as I know, other than convnets, recurrent neural network only learns the sequential relation of the data, but it doesn't create any new features, right?